# python group of words search implemented recursively. How to proceed?

Tags: python, recursion, scikit-learn, text-mining

I have to look for concepts within texts. The concepts are expressed in the following way:

`"blue 5 house"` >>> would mean that I have to find the hits where the words `blue` and `house` appear within a `distance of 5 or less words`.
`"little 3 cat"` would then mean finding the hits where the words `little` and `cat` appear within a `distance of max 3 words`. (i.e. "little cat", "little annoying cat" but not "the cat of my grandmother is little")

I guess you get it.

I have so far a (not very sophisticated) code as follows. I just implemented two nested loops that go over all the words of the text and when there is a hit of the first one start to look for the other one in the words around and adds the result to a list:

```
with open('applicationtext.txt', 'r') as f:
content=f.read()
# content = ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur (23) adipiscing elit, sed do ( 23 , 45 ) eiusmod ( 23, 45 ) tempor incididunt ut  '
# Note: the text contains several times: "sit amet eros vestibulum"

elasticTerm1="sit"
elasticTerm2="vestibulum"
distance=5

content=content.strip()
# replace all the line breaks and two spaces.
content = content.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').replace('  ',' ')

listofHits=[]
content_tokenized = content.split(" ")

for i,word in enumerate(content_tokenized):
    if word==elasticTerm1:
        for j in range(distance):
            if content_tokenized[i+j]==elasticTerm2:
                # I got a hit
                position1=i
                myhitTupple=(i,elasticTerm1)
                listofHits.append(myhitTupple)

for i,tupple in enumerate(listofHits):
    print(tupple)
```

So far it works ok.

Imagine I am thinking about how to build on that in order to construct code something recursively that would give me the hits of:

`(little 3 cat) 4 third_word` or even
`concept1 5 concept2`; where `concept1=("blue 3 cat")` and `concept2=("little 4 dollar")`???

what should I think about? a class? is that already somehow contained in scikit-learn? More than a code (which I guess would be complicated) I am asking you for orientation. How to think about a problem solved with code recursively.

Thanks

NOTE 1: Please forget about the order "little cat" vs "cat little" thats another issue.

NOTE 2: (after first answer) Be aware that this is a very simplified case, in reality I am looking at cases like this: `((concept1 n1 concept2) n2 concept 3)) n3 (concept1 n4 concept 5)`

Comment: You must use that "elastic search"? I think that with regex you could do it in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key observations underlying the solution:

- when we take the leap from tokens to "concepts",we need range instead of index.
- We need to define a function to find "distance" between two concepts i.e their corresponding range. (`dist` below)
- another function to combine concepts i.e their ranges. (`comb` below)

Now in our main recursive function, we first find out all occurrences of both concepts. Then we can simply find the pairs which have distance lower than specified. In this implementation, our main `hits()` takes a "concept":which is either simply a word in base case, or a 3-element tuple that have two concepts and an `int` specifying max possible distance between them. Output of this function is an array of ranges, where each of these ranges contain both concepts withing max distance. This array can be thought of as all occurrences of the input concept.

Here is the full code.

```
#Find distance between two concept's ranges
#ex1: dist([2,9],[11,13]) = 2
#ex2: dist([2,9],[4,99]) = 0
def dist(r1,r2):
    #check for overlap
    if r2[0]<=r1[0]<=r2[1] or r1[0]<=r2[0]<=r1[1]:
        return 0

    return max(r1[0],r2[0]) - min(r1[1],r2[1])

#Combine two concept's ranges
#ex1: comb([1,3],[6,9]) = [1,9]
#ex2: comb([4,11],[1,7]) = [1,11]
def comb(r1,r2): 
    return [min(r1[0],r2[0]),max(r1[1],r2[1])]

def hits(concept):
    if type(concept)==str:
        return [(i,i) for i,w in enumerate(tokens) if w==concept]

    c1,c2,R = concept
    ans = []
    for r1 in hits(c1):
        for r2 in hits(c2):
            if dist(r1,r2)<=R:
                ans.append(comb(r1,r2))
    return ans
```

To test this, case 1: (this outputs [[0-9]])

```
tokens = "python group of words search implemented recursively How to proceed".split()
c1 = ("python","words",3)
c2 = ("recursively","proceed",4)
print(hits((c1,c2,3)))
```

case 2: (this outputs [[0-8]])

```
c1 = ("python","of",3)
c2 = ("search","recursively",4)
print(hits(((c1,c2,3),"to",3)))
```

Case 3: (This outputs [[0, 3], [6, 8]])

```
tokens = "A B B X C C X Q A W".split()
c1 = ("A","X",4)
print(hits(c1))
```

For performance, preprocess the base case of recursion.

Comment: Thanks Shihab, this is wo powerfull!!!! I will try it out the coming days